# How do I exit Python if run from command line, otherwise print stack trace

Tags: python, exception, exit

I want to exit Python if I encounter an exception in my function if that function is being executed from the command line, but want to raise an exception and print a stack trace if the my function is not run from the command line.

Right now I have

```
    try:
        #...
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR: Some useful message')
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            raise e
```

but I feel like I'm either doing too much here, or too little.

Is there an idiomatic way to get a stack trace with the original exception when my function is run from the command line; but simply exit if it is being run from the command line?

Comment: could you rephrase this `Is there an idiomatic way to get a stack trace with the original exception when my function is run from the command line; but simply exit if it is being run from the command line?`. I'm not sure if that makes. thanks.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: Fixed, I think.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent your end users from seeing a traceback?  If so, I'm not sure I agree with the wisdom of this strategy.  Tracebacks contain useful information for you, the programmer.  If the end user can just copy and paste the traceback, it can save you a fair amount of debugging time.

Comment: @Kevin: It's not that kind of error. Here `try` is just a test for something. When used from the command line in the context of a isolated command, it could fail without downstream consequences. But if the function has been imported and used, the user importing probably needs to decide for himself whether to exit, so I show the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

The better way would be to do this:

```
import sys

def func():
    do_actual_processing()
    if not successful:
        raise Exception("Yadayada")

if __name__ == '__main__'
    try:
        func()
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(1)
```

That is, the function itself does not need to be concerned with whether or not it is run from command line.

Comment: Oh wait, I know why: I don't want to do this for all exceptions, or even for all exceptions of a give class. Just for certain exceptions in certain places in the code. E.g., I could have another exception happen somewhere else in my code and not want to exit, ever.

Comment: Sounds like bad design. I would do a `main` function then for command line usage, it really is not a good idea to make a function do something completely different just because `__name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way (or maybe I'm asking the wrong question): If this is executed from the command line I want to print a message of my own and exit; but if it's not, I want the stack trace and the original exception.

Comment: The context is that each of these functions (there are several) corresponds to a command for a script (e.g. `myscript.py func`). I don't want a full stack trace if that fails; but to just exit with a simple message like "Something I need to proceed isn't here". But if `func` has been imported and is being used, say, in IPython, I want to be more informative, with the full trace and original exception.

Comment: Then why not do as I said, this hardly invalidates my answer.

Comment: See my second comment: There will be cases where the same exception elsewhere (in other commands or even another part of `func`) should always be preserved and generate a stack trace.